# Indexing huge data (~12 million rows) from postgreSQL to Elasticsearch is VERY SLOW

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, elasticsearch, optimization

I am using `postgreSQL` and I'm trying to bring power of `Elasticsearch` to our system. I am using this algorithm to bulk insert data (each time **1000 rows** of data) into Elasticsearch. The problem is it is very very slow and took about **15 hours** for just **280 000** rows of data.

From my estimate it is going to take about **26 days** non stop to complete indexing just this table (**with ~12M records**).

Is it possible to somehow optimize this approach and create a faster one? this is what I'm doing so far:

```
public function run()
    {
        $es_client = new \Elastica\Client();
        $es_index = $es_client->getIndex("vehicle");
        $es_type = $es_index->getType("_doc");

        $vehicle_ins = new Vehicle;

        $step = 1000;
        $min_vehicle_id = $vehicle_ins->query()->min('id');
        $max_vehicle_id = $vehicle_ins->query()->max('id');

        $insert_counter = 1;

        $docs = [];

        for ($i = $min_vehicle_id ; $i <= $max_vehicle_id ; $i += $step) {
            $x = $i;
            $y = $i + $step;

            $vehicles = $vehicle_ins->query()
                ->where('id', '>=', $x)
                ->where('id', '<', $y)
                ->get();

            foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {

                $docs[] = new \Elastica\Document(
                    $vehicle->id,
                    [
                        // implementing my columns (91 columns)
                    ]);

                echo ".";

                if ($insert_counter % $step == 0) {
                    $es_type->addDocuments($docs);
                    $es_type->getIndex()->refresh();
                    $docs = [];
                    echo "\n";
                    echo $step . " rows inserted!";
                    echo "\n";
                }

                $insert_counter++;

            }
        }
        if (!empty($docs)) {
            $es_type->addDocuments($docs);
            $es_type->getIndex()->refresh();
            $docs = [];
        }
    }
```

P.S: I am using `elastica` for working with `Elasticsearch` and the application is in `Laravel 5.7` with `postgreSQL` as the main DB.

P.S: This approach was also suggested in [**ElasticSearch website**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html#_bulk_indexing), but it's still too slow for the amount of data I'm working with.

Comment: Do you need to call `refresh` after every `addDocument` operation? Also laravel has a built-in [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects) method that "pages" your results for you so no need for that kind of selection

Comment: `->where('id', '>=', $x)->where('id', '<', $y)` may be slow if there's no index for id and also it will definitely be slower than `skip($x)->take($step)` which internally uses `limit ... offset` and will not need to actually do any comparison on the row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of some methods inside of my `Vehicle model` that performed some changes in each attribute after getting them from the database and these unwanted changes made the process very very slow.

The solution is to query data using `Laravel DB facade` until those attribute changer methods get removed or transferred to somewhere else from the **Vehicle model**.

So the queries should look like this:

```
$min_vehicle_id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('vehicle')->min('id');
$max_vehicle_id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('vehicle')->max('id');
```

and this for getting the data:

```
$vehicles = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('vehicle')
                ->where('id', '>=', $x)
                ->where('id', '<', $y)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) to your **index**. Also check if you need analysis of each field - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-index.html

Comment: I don't have to do any analysis now since I'm just trying to index everything as they are in the db for now. but about mapping, do you think it really improves the speed? because the part that Elasticsearch inserts 1000 data is pretty fast. it's slow when the data is being created and ready for insert

Comment: Here are more tips -https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/tune-for-indexing-speed.html (Increase the refresh interval, Disable refresh and replicas for initial loads, Use auto-generated ids)